# installing jruby on MacOS compared to ruby on Windows OS Box

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm looking to install jruby for development on Macbook Pro.
Does it do me any good in terms of improved performance compared to just running ruby on a windows-os running box? I mean I'm aiming to install Jruby on MacOS to take advantage of performance improvement of the platform.

anyone could enlighten me with this?

Answer (score 1):

JRuby is faster than 1.9 MRI ("Matz' Ruby Interpreter", the standard) in certain areas. Windows versus OS X is irrelevant. (Do you believe that MRI on Windows is faster than MRI on OS X on the same hardware? I know of at least one case where the opposite is true.)

However, a slightly faster interpreter is not going to make your development significantly faster.

I basically don't understand your motives, needs, or question. Hopefully the information I've given you helps nonetheless. If not, please consider explaining what you need to do and are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Phrogz. I'm just feeling that my current development setup, which is MRI on windows 7 is rather slow. I'm just looking if any suggestion on setup combination, whether interpreter or OS? Sorry, if my question is a little not very clear, but trying to get you to understand.

Comment: @sarunnio Slow in what way? Do you believe the OS X JVM is faster than the Windows JVM? What aspect of performance do you believe you'll improve?